# C# HttpClient GET returns 200 but an empty array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient, httpresponsemessage

I've been trying to use HttpClient, to connect to an API. I'm able to send a GET request and  recieve the desired data that I want from it through Postman and Fiddler, without issue.

The issue is that the json file i get from the HttpClient is: `[]`

The HttpClient gives me the **Status 200** while providing me with an empty array.

```
    public class CoolModel
    {
         public string name { get; set; }
         public int itemId{ get; set; }
         public string Devicename{ get; set; }
    }
```

```
var username = _config["Username"];
var password = _config[":Password"];
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password)));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", _config["ApiKey"]);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# App");

HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(_config["Url"] + $"item?ID={_config["ItemId"]}&DeviceName={_config["DeviceName"]}").Result;
       
var json = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoolModel>>(json);
```

This will return the following:
`[]`

While what I want is:

```
[
    {
        "name":"John",
        "itemId":30,
        "Devicename":"something"
    }
]
```

My json that is returned is also
`[]`

Comment: Does the `List<CoolModel>` type match with the returned response (pattern)?  Did you try to debug to see what is the `json` value?

Comment: Maybe the members of your `CoolModel` are Field instead of Properties; nobody knows, you didn't post the model. -- Why are you awating `ReadAsStringAsync()` but not `GetAsync()` one line before? Await both; don't block (that's what `Result` does) when you have async code.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint at ·content· to see the value? And what did you return?

Comment: @YongShun The json value is ```[]```
@QingGuo I can only assume that Content is the same

Comment: @Jimi Sorry for not saying what the model is but they're properties.

Comment: @Jimi Added the model as you asked, and the JSON I recieve is ```[]```

Comment: @groundclutter What is about your `httpResponse` ?

Comment: @Jimi it is just ```[]``` I get 200 from the request, but I recieve an empty json. That is before i deserialized it. It is just 


```Log.Error("Json output: {0}", json);

//Returns

[06:32:59 ERR] Json output: []
```

Comment: Then move the URL you're passing to `GetAsync()` out of there, assign it to a string variable and check what the content of that string actually is. It's quite possible that you get an empty array because the query doesn't return results based on the criteria you have set.

Comment: @QingGuo is there anything specific you want from it?

Comment: Try "HttpResponseMessage httpResponse  = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Empty, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead); " to see  what you get. @groundclutter

Comment: @Jimi ```https://MyCoolUrl.com/cool/api/item?ID=30&

DeviceName=something``` Like this? It is the same as in postman and fiddler, it looks like its broken into two parts in the log

Comment: @QingGuo I get an exception when I do the ```HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Empty, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);``` 
The Exception: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set

Comment: @Jimi I'll try to fix it, it appears that its trying to send the request with the break, I wrote it off as the log didn't have enough spaces to show the full url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that the Url

```
var url = _config["Url"] + $"item?ID={_config["ItemId"]}&DeviceName={_config["DeviceName"]}"
```

Contained empty new lines, so I had to remove the new lines.
so I added the following to my url
`.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""));`

````
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""));```
````

Answer (score 1):

Below is a demo about using  HttpClient to connect to an API, you can refer to it.

```
    [Route("home")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
        {
            string url = $"https://localhost:7272/weatherForecast";

            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
            };

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
          
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

            httpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Empty, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WeatherForecast>>(json);

            return View(content);


        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my issue was that the was a new line in the enviorement

Answer (score 0):

Fix your model, id should be an integer

```
 public class CoolModel
    {
         public string name { get; set; }
         public int id { get; set; }
         public string devicename { get; set; }
    }
```